# position of a signal in a vector

Tags: matlab

I have 4 signals: $z,c,d$ and $r$. $r$ is defined by: $r=[c,z,d,z]$

I would like to find signal $d$. In Matlab I do this:

```
r2=r(size(c,2)+size(z,2)+(0:size(d,2)-1))
```

Do we have $r2=d$?

Comment: Have you tried running your code and seeing if it works?

Comment: Don’t forget that Matlab has 1-based indexing

Answer (score 1):

**In case the four vectors are row vectors**

```
r2=r(size(c,2)+size(z,2)+1:end-size(z,2))
```

**In case the four vectors are column vectors**

```
r2 = r(:,3)
```

PS: thanks @ThP

Comment: Unless they are row vectors